# C# AES Key file

Tags: c#, key, aes

I am trying to save a AES256 key in plain text in a file. When I straight write the bytes, and open the file in notepad, I see a bunch of garbage. I have tried to UTF encode the bytes, but perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Here is the code:

```
public static bool GenerateAes256KeyFile()
{            
    SymmetricAlgorithm aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    aesAlg.GenerateKey();

    //System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    //string key = encoder.GetString(aesAlg.Key);
    //File.WriteAllText(keyFile, aesAlg.Key);
    File.WriteAllBytes(keyFile, aesAlg.Key);
    return true;
}
```

I have tried the encoding in the comments as well, and get a *different* kind of garbage text.

I am probably just missing something simple as I am new to C#. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A key is a series of random bytes which will look like garbage if put in a file as-is. Trying to decode a bunch of random bytes as UTF-8 also makes no sense and will likely result in an error. *What kind* of plain text do you want to convert it to?

Comment: the key **IS** random garbage. converting it to utf-8 will randomly corrupt the key, because some of those random bytes can map to actual utf8 characters. you don't want utf, you want something like base64

Comment: You can use `Convert.ToBase64String` (to read: `Convert.FromBase64String`)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marc and Eser. The solution was to use Convert.ToBase64String.